# Flutter Range Error Invalid Value with ListView, not Builder

Tags: flutter

**The Error:** `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

> The relevant error-causing widget was
>
> MainMenu
>
> lib\main.dart:659
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
>
> #0      List._setIndexed (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:262:73)
>
> #1      List.[]= (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:258:5)
>
> #2      getMenuArrays
>
> package:j_deli/menu/menu_main.dart:92
>
> #3      createMenuLists
>
> package:j_deli/menu/menu_main.dart:67
>
> #4      MainMenu.build

**Goal:** Load different arrays of container widgets into a list view from a selection of a Navigation rail item with the variable *_selectedIndex*.

**Note:** I do not get an error when I comment out `var menuLists = createMenuLists();` so the problem is coming from the instantiation of my list of a list of widgets (Container widgets). I understand I'm working with dynamic lists but not sure at all why this code doesn't work. It seems to break from this method specifically. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

```
class MainMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  int _selectedIndex;
  var menuCategoriesArray;
  int numberOfItemsInCart = 0;

  MainMenu(this._selectedIndex, this.menuCategoriesArray);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var menuLists = createMenuLists();

    return ListView(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: Text(
                menuCategoriesArray[_selectedIndex],
                style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                    fontSize: 39, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
                    Text(numberOfItemsInCart.toString()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        menuLists[_selectedIndex],
      ],
    );
  }
}





createMenuCard(int whichMenuItem, var currentMenuList) {
  return MenuCard(
      currentMenuList[0][whichMenuItem],
      currentMenuList[1][whichMenuItem],
      currentMenuList[2][whichMenuItem],
      currentMenuList[3][whichMenuItem]);
}

createMenuList(int numberOfItemsInMenuList, var currentMenuList) {
  var listMenuOfCards;

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInMenuList; i++) {
    listMenuOfCards[i] = createMenuCard(i, currentMenuList);
  }

  return listMenuOfCards;
}

createMenuLists() {
  var menuLists;

  for (int i = 0; i < getMenuArrays().length; i++) {
    menuLists[i] =
        createMenuList(getMenuArrays()[i][0].length, getMenuArrays()[i]);
  }

  return menuLists;
}

getMenuArrays() {
  //THE PIT MENU

  var nameArray = [
    'Angus Beef Brisket',
    'Pulled Pork',
    '1/2 BBQ Chicken',
    'St. Louis Style Pork Ribs - 6 Ribs',
    'St. Louis Style Pork Ribs - 12 Ribs',
    'Tri-Tip'
  ];

  var imageArray = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
    imageArray[i] = 'assets/images/empty_image.jpg';
  }

  var summaryArray = [
    'Slow smoked, sliced to provide perfect mix of brisket',
    'Pork butt dry rubbed, slow smoked, hand pulled daily',
    'Rocky\'s chicken, local favorite',
    'Extra meaty, dry rubbed, slow smoked',
    'Extra meaty, dry rubbed, slow smoked',
    'Black Angus tri-tip trimmed in house, dry rubbed and slow smoked',
  ];

  var priceArray = ['22.00', '20.00', '21.00', '22.00', '35', '23'];

  var menuArrays;

  menuArrays[0] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
  menuArrays[1] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
  menuArrays[2] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
  menuArrays[3] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
  menuArrays[4] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
  menuArrays[5] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
  menuArrays[6] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
  menuArrays[7] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];

  return menuArrays;
}
```

**Edit:** I think the error might be occurring due to how I am instantiating a list of lists in the getMenuArrays() method at the end.

**Edit 2:** I added some debugPrint()s and they are indicating the error is occurring when I try to set the values of menuArray to other arrays, here:

> var menuArrays;
>
> ```
>   menuArrays[0] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
>   menuArrays[1] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
>   menuArrays[2] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
>   menuArrays[3] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
>   menuArrays[4] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
>   menuArrays[5] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
>   menuArrays[6] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
>   menuArrays[7] = [imageArray, nameArray, summaryArray, priceArray];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using .add instead of [0] = ... [1] = ... for each of the items in the menuArrays array. I also had to use .toList():

```
menuArrays.add([imageArray.toList(), nameArray.toList(), summaryArray.toList(), priceArray.toList()]);
```

Not entirely sure why, but this worked. All in all, don't use [n] = ... for lists. Use .add because they are not arrays with set lengths.